# Is there any ferry from Vietnam to Hong Kong?

Tags: ferries, hong-kong, cruising, vietnam

I would like to have an Asia trip from Malaysia to Hong Kong (if possible).

Is there anyone who has been doing this kind of trip? And I wonder if there is any sea transportation that provides a connection between Hong Kong and Vietnam?

Comment: Besides trains from Hong Kong to Vietnam, you may also wish to consider taking buses especially between the Vietnam-China border. The booking of bus tickets are usually handled through travel agents.

Answer (score 6):

There are no "ferries" that travel the route. Ferries are not available for this distance since the minimum distance (bee line) from Hong Kong to Vietnam is 600+ kilometers. You would rather get on board a cruise ship.

Here are [some cruises](http://www.cruisecompete.com/vacations/visits/viet_nam/1) departing from various places in Vietnam, [this one here](http://www.cruisecompete.com/itins/mariner_of_the_seas_cruises_baihajej.html) for example going from Singapore via Vietnam to Hong Kong.

As an alternative, and maybe more interesting, you can also [take a train](http://www.seat61.com/Vietnam.htm#Hong%20Kong). However this will require you to get a Chinese visa, which the boat does not need.